# Simplifying SQL Select (att1, att2) union (att2, att1) to avoid copy and paste

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try to simplify the following code, but I can't seem to get the syntax right other than to copy and paste which makes the code hard to read. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

```
select att1, att2 from LONG EXPRESSION 
union
select att2, att1 from LONG EXPRESSION
```

I was hoping to do

```
select att1, att2 union select att2, att1
from LONG EXPRESSION
```

or something like

```
select att1, att2 from LONG EXPRESSION X
union
select att2, att1 from X
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my phone, so please forgive formatting :)

```
SELECT (CASE multiplier.ID WHEN 0 THEN src.att1 ELSE src.att2 END), 
       (CASE multiplier.ID WHEN 1 THEN src.att1 ELSE src.att2 END)
FROM LONG_EXPRESSION src CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 0 AS ID
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS ID
     ) multiplier
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a common table expression aka CTE:

```
with t as (
    select att1, att2
    from LONG EXPRESSION 
   )
select t.att1, t.att2
from t
union all
select t.att2, t.att1
from t;
```

Note that I used `union all` instead of `union`. This is preferable -- unless you intentionally want to incur the overhead of eliminating duplicates.

Comment: Didn't know that `Sqlite` supports CTE although,I would prefer normal UNION DML. +1 for CTE approach

Comment: The Sqlite I am using doesn't have the syntax "with" it gave an error, but thanks for the tips for CTE. Definitely useful to learn about it.